# Unable to figure out how to prevent crash with Date type and wrapping in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I'm working with MPMediaQuery and specifically Podcasts. I'm having a very difficult time with Optionals and wrapping/unwrapping in this particular case.

```
    titleFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: selectedPodcastTitle, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPodcastTitle, comparisonType: .equalTo)
    qryPodcasts.addFilterPredicate(titleFilter)

    for junk in qryPodcasts.items!{

        //works fine
        if let sTitle  = junk.title {
            print("episode title: \(sTitle)")
        }else{
            print("episode title is nil")
        }

        //works fine
        if let dRelease = junk.releaseDate {
            print("episode release date: \(dRelease)")
        }else{
            print("episode release date is nil")
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // can't figure out how to make this work
            // crashes on some podcasts and I suspect it's when 'addedDate' is nil
            if let dAdded: Date = junk.dateAdded {
                print("episode added date: \(junk.dateAdded)")
            }else{
                print("episode added date is nil")
            }
        } else {
            print("episode added date is not available")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and following the flow of the program? Maybe there's a side effect of something going on. 

Also try, instead of using the property accessor, `junk.value(forProperty: the date added key)` and see what that gives you. If it is null or something funky, you may have stumbled into a swift bug.

Comment: I don't see a date added key actually.

Comment: Hope you figure this out, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the nullability of `dateAdded` is wrongly annotated in the current iOS SDK, and you may need some workaround.

Try this extension:

```
extension MPMediaItem {
    func getAddedDate() -> Date? {
        return self.perform(#selector(getter: MPMediaItem.dateAdded))?.takeUnretainedValue() as! NSDate? as Date?
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
        if let dAdded = junk.getAddedDate() {
            print("episode added date: \(dAdded)")
        }else{
            print("episode added date is nil")
        }
```

---

You'd better send a bug report to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) about this issue. (It may be classified as duplicate, but the number may affect.)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One thing to note is that "dateAdded" is only available since iOS 10 so I had to wrap both the extension clause and my usage like so: `extension MPMediaItem {
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func getAddedDate() -> Date? {
        return self.perform(#selector(getter: MPMediaItem.dateAdded))?.takeUnretainedValue() as! NSDate? as Date?
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

After the last discussion, the `dateAdded` has un-nullable type `Date` and crash happen when it = nil.

So I recommend it type should `Date?` and you should unwrapping it.

```
 if let dAdded = junk.dateAdded {
 }
```

or check it will `nil` at this situation.

```
 if junk.dateAdded != nil {
 }
```

Comment: dateAdded is typed as `var dateAdded: Date { get }`. The compiler knows the type. Also it's not a nullable type, but that only gives a warning.

Comment: Did it crash when `dateAdded = nil` right at `let dAdded: Date = junk.dateAdded` ?

Comment: Regardless of the methods I use it is crashing at the "let" or "if" line. I changed to if    junk.dateAdded != nil    and the compiler is stating "Comparing non-optional value of type 'Date' to nil always returns true"

Comment: Also, if I use   `if let dAdded = junk.dateAdded`   the compiler complains: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Date' "

Comment: Yes. Because it's type is un-nullable `Date`. You should change `dateAdded` type to `Date` to `Date?` because it can be nil. Or you have to find out why it nil in init?

Comment: Can't change to `Date` or `Date?` - compiler complains "Non-optional expression of type 'Date' used in a check for optionals"

Comment: Where compiler show that error? Can you update more code where you init the `junk`.